# calculate $\text{cov}(\bar{X_n},X_{(1)})$

Tags: mathematical-statistics

Suppose $X_1, \dots , X_n$ is a random sample from $f(x|\mu,\sigma)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sigma}\displaystyle e^{\displaystyle-\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}}, x>\mu , \sigma>0$. How can calculate $\text{cov}(\bar{X_n},X_{(1)})$. *Note:* $X_{(1)}$ is first order statistics.

Comment: please add the `self-study` tag and the `order statistics` tag.

Comment: you do not appear to have attempted to answer the question yourself or give any indication as to where you're struggling.  Please add more info

Comment: You're posting a lot of homework. Please read the relevant info in the [self-study tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) - in particular the first three items under **Asking about self-study questions**.

Comment: Why so many downvotes? I think this is an interesting problem. If it was homework, I'd probably wait for the assignment to expire before answering :) ... but I think it's a nice little problem.

Answer (score 2):

I give an outline of the approach here; if you give more details as @probabilityislogic suggests, I could perhaps be a little more specific about the parts giving particular trouble.

Expand $\bar{X}$ as a constant times a sum of terms. Use the properties of covariances to move the constant outside the covariance operator and to write a covariance involving a sum as a sum of covariances. Explain why that sum simplifies to a single term. Figure out what that term is (you will end up with a constant times some variance, which judging from your large number of previous questions on this particular topic you should already have the answer to).

Answer (score 2):

It helps to recall that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(X_i-X_{(1)})$ and $X_{(1)}$ are [independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3206984/321264), so they are also uncorrelated.

Now,

\begin{align}
0=\operatorname{Cov}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-X_{(1)}),X_{(1)}\right)&=\operatorname{Cov}(n\overline X_n-nX_{(1)},X_{(1)})
\\&=n\operatorname{Cov}(\overline X_n,X_{(1)})-n\operatorname{Var}(X_{(1)}).
\end{align}

Hence it must be that $$\operatorname{Cov}(\overline X_n,X_{(1)})=\operatorname{Var}(X_{(1)})$$